# My stellar-core can't run on the Public

Tags: stellar-core

I just want to run a node which can download the public data.my config stellar-core.cfg like this:

```
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar_core user=stellar password=123456 host=localhost"
#配置数据存储路径
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/data/coin/xlm/"
#设置http暴露接口
HTTP_PORT=11626
#设置和其他节点互联的端口
PEER_PORT=11625
LOG_FILE_PATH=""

# This is an example config for setting up a validator.
# see https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/learn/admin.html
# for how to properly configure your environment

# run `stellar-core --genseed` to generate a public key and secret seed.
# Let us know the public key so we can add you to the validator list.
# set NODE_SEED below to the secret seed generated above.

# uncomment those two lines if you are running a validator node
# NODE_SEED="S123456ABCDE"
# NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

#FAILURE_SAFETY is minimum number of nodes that are allowed to fail before you no longer have quorum
FAILURE_SAFETY=1

# number of ledgers to synchronize (time in seconds divided by 5)
# NB: full validators should run with CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true instead
#CATCHUP_RECENT=60480
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true
NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"


NODE_NAMES=[
    "GAOO3LWBC4XF6VWRP5ESJ6IBHAISVJMSBTALHOQM2EZG7Q477UWA6L7U  eno",
    "GAXP5DW4CVCW2BJNPFGTWCEGZTJKTNWFQQBE5SCWNJIJ54BOHR3WQC3W  moni",
    "GBFZFQRGOPQC5OEAWO76NOY6LBRLUNH4I5QYPUYAK53QSQWVTQ2D4FT5  dzham",
    "GDXWQCSKVYAJSUGR2HBYVFVR7NA7YWYSYK3XYKKFO553OQGOHAUP2PX2  jianing",
    "GCJCSMSPIWKKPR7WEPIQG63PDF7JGGEENRC33OKVBSPUDIRL6ZZ5M7OO  tempo.eu.com",
    "GCCW4H2DKAC7YYW62H3ZBDRRE5KXRLYLI4T5QOSO6EAMUOE37ICSKKRJ  sparrow_tw",
    "GD5DJQDDBKGAYNEAXU562HYGOOSYAEOO6AS53PZXBOZGCP5M2OPGMZV3  fuxi.lab",
    "GBGGNBZVYNMVLCWNQRO7ASU6XX2MRPITAGLASRWOWLB4ZIIPHMGNMC4I  huang.lab",
    "GDPJ4DPPFEIP2YTSQNOKT7NMLPKU2FFVOEIJMG36RCMBWBUR4GTXLL57  nezha.lab",
    "GCDLFPQ76D6YUSCUECLKI3AFEVXFWVRY2RZH2YQNYII35FDECWUGV24T  SnT.Lux",
    "GBAR4OY6T6M4P344IF5II5DNWHVUJU7OLQPSMG2FWVJAFF642BX5E3GB  telindus",
# non validating
    "GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH  sdf_watcher1",
    "GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK  sdf_watcher2",
    "GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ  sdf_watcher3",
    # seem down
    "GB6REF5GOGGSEHZ3L2YK6K4T4KX3YDMWHDCPMV7MZJDLHBDNZXEPRBGM  donovan",
    "GBGR22MRCIVW2UZHFXMY5UIBJGPYABPQXQ5GGMNCSUM2KHE3N6CNH6G5  nelisky1",
    "GA2DE5AQF32LU5OZ5OKAFGPA2DLW4H6JHPGYJUVTNS3W7N2YZCTQFFV6  nelisky2",
    "GDJ73EX25GGUVMUBCK6DPSTJLYP3IC7I3H2URLXJQ5YP56BW756OUHIG  w00kie",
    "GAM7A32QZF5PJASRSGVFPAB36WWTHCBHO5CHG3WUFTUQPT7NZX3ONJU4  ptarasov"
    ]

    # NODE_IS_VALIDATOR (boolean) default false.
    # Only nodes that want to participate in SCP should set NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true.
    # Most instances should operate in observer mode with NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=false.
    # See QUORUM_SET below.
    NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=false

    KNOWN_PEERS=[
    "core-live-a.stellar.org:11625",
    "core-live-b.stellar.org:11625",
    "core-live-c.stellar.org:11625",
    "confucius.strllar.org",
    "stellar1.bitventure.co",
    "stellar.256kw.com"]



[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=[
"$sdf_watcher1","$eno","$tempo.eu.com","$sdf_watcher2","$sdf_watcher3"]
[HISTORY.cache]
get="cp /opt/stellar/history-cache/{0} {1}"

# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.stellar]
get="curl http://history.stellar.org/{0} -o {1}"
# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.sdf1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.sdf3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Somewhere is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks all fine from the status `"status" : [ "Catching up: downloading ledger files 18/357318 (0%)"`.

You can see the downloading is `18/357318`, **not** something like `0/357318`. That means it is running and doing work.

Just be patient. The process can take hours or days to finish the sync process, as the data size is enormous.

---

Show further syndromes if you see the status hanging up at this process for hours.

Comment: Thanks, but it don't sync. If I set "CATCHUP_RECENT=60480", it would be ok very soon?

Comment: in this case, i guess it would take less than an hour to Sync. Just that you are getting the most recent 60480 ledgers, i.e. ledger number 22868498-60480=`22808018` to `22868498`, instead of all ledgers starting from number 1

Comment: if you change the config, remember to do `stellar-core --forcescp` and then restart your stellar-core.

Answer (score 0):

root@coin04:/data/coin# curl 127.0.0.1:11626/info

```
{
   "info" : {
      "build" : "v10.3.0rc1-4-gb8077bf",
      "history_failure_rate" : "0.16",
      "ledger" : {
         "age" : 1552277052,
         "baseFee" : 100,
         "baseReserve" : 100000000,
         "closeTime" : 0,
         "hash" : "39c2a3cd4141b2853e70d84601faa44744660334b48f3228e0309342e3f4eb48",
         "maxTxSetSize" : 100,
         "num" : 1,
         "version" : 0
      },
      "network" : "Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015",
      "peers" : {
         "authenticated_count" : 8,
         "pending_count" : 4
      },
      "protocol_version" : 10,
      "quorum" : {
         "22868498" : {
            "agree" : 4,
            "delayed" : 0,
            "disagree" : 0,
            "fail_at" : 1,
            "hash" : "ba2fc8",
            "missing" : 1,
            "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE"
         }
      },
      "startedOn" : "2019-03-11T03:46:13Z",
      "state" : "Catching up",
      "status" : [ "Catching up: downloading ledger files 18/357318 (0%)" ]
   }
}
```

catching up status, it is alway this status.
I found it can't sync.

Answer (score 0):

Now, status is like this.
curl 127.0.0.1:11626/info

```
{
   "info" : {
      "build" : "v10.3.0rc1-4-gb8077bf",
      "history_failure_rate" : "0.16",
      "ledger" : {
         "age" : 1552284496,
         "baseFee" : 100,
         "baseReserve" : 100000000,
         "closeTime" : 0,
         "hash" : "39c2a3cd4141b2853e70d84601faa44744660334b48f3228e0309342e3f4eb48",
         "maxTxSetSize" : 100,
         "num" : 1,
         "version" : 0
      },
      "network" : "Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015",
      "peers" : {
         "authenticated_count" : 8,
         "pending_count" : 0
      },
      "protocol_version" : 10,
      "quorum" : {
         "22869874" : {
            "agree" : 5,
            "delayed" : 0,
            "disagree" : 0,
            "fail_at" : 2,
            "hash" : "ba2fc8",
            "missing" : 0,
            "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE"
         }
      },
      "startedOn" : "2019-03-11T03:46:13Z",
      "state" : "Catching up",
      "status" : [ "Catching up: downloading ledger files 20/357318 (0%)" ]
   }
}
```

Comment: as you could see, `18/357318` --> `20/357318`, so it is making some slow progress... just that it might be really slow to you.